# LINQ Specify multiple conditions

Tags: c#, linq

How do I specify more than one condition in the below LINQ?

```
if (Books.Select(x => x.BookName).Count() !=
    Books.Select(x => x.BookName).Distinct().Count())
{
    //Todo
}
```

I want to specify some thing Like this:

```
if (Books.Select(x => x.BookName && x.price).Count() !=
    Books.Select(x => x.BookName && x.price).Distinct().Count())
{
    //Todo
}
```

Comment: What you mean by `condition`? The only condition that I have see a `count != distinct count`.

Comment: Condition in Select Query: x => x.BookName && x.price

Comment: In English: There should not be two books with the same price and the same name. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a select for getting the first count. You can use an anonymous type for getting the second count. This will get number of distinct book name and prices:

```
if (Books.Count() != Books.Select(x => new { x.BookName, x.price}).Distinct().Count())
{
    //Todo
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So, to answer your question, project each item out into an anonymous type.

However, to avoid iterating the source data multiple times (which is particularly problematic if `Book` represents a database query), and to avoid performing the projection repeatedly, you can use `GroupBy` instead:

```
bool areDuplicatedBooks = Books.GroupBy(x => new{x.BookName, x.price})
    .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
    .Any()
```